# A miracle for finding a stolen phone

Tags: lost-phone, htc-one-m8

## Background

Recently my phone got stolen from my pocket and then I was almost thrown in street and run over by a car. The police won't move a finger because of a new law, which means I'll have to wait for over a year to get it back, but of course I did file a complaint with all the documents regarding the ownership of the phone.

## Question

Is there any possibility of tracking your phone considering the fact that you have no pre-installed or rooted app and even if you do have it they can do factory reset/boot or do a full wipe? Can you track your IMEI or is there a service that could track it for you?

Comment: Not much help now, but for future reference - I always install a custom ROM, and sideload something like Cerberus right in, that say even a factory reset will not clear it, only a new ROM install would.

Answer (score 2):

Yea there is one miracle app which should be already installed in your device. Android Device Manager is built into all Android phones and allows you to do almost anything you want and you can operate it with your google account that you used on your mobile but it only works when GPS is activated.

Comment: If they do a factory reset you google account is no more linked to the phone and therefor the app is useless. I tried it already..